# What actually happens when a computer is deleted from Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

If I open AD and then delete a computer, what will happen to that computer? Will it physically get removed from the domain? What would happen if I tried to log into the computer after it had been deleted?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: What Grant said.  When you try to log in, it'll give you the "The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship" error message and fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that you are not deleting a *computer* but a *computer account*

Just like deleting a user doesnt eject then from the building, deleting the computer account will just mean the computer can no longer access the domain.

Domain logins will fail because the domain controller won't talk to it. Computers need those accounts, with the right password, to access things like group policy shares.

But the computer will still think its on the domain, just like the guy about to be fired thinks he still works here.